# How can I convert a cell array into a numeric array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, numeric, cell-array

I'm stuck with a supposedly simple problem in MATLAB. I have a 1x43 cell array that looks like this (note the space before each value):

```
labels = {' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ... , ' 43'};
```

And I simply want to convert it to a numeric vector of dimensions 1x43 that will look like this:

```
labels_numeric = [1 2 3 ... 43];
```

Anyone could hint me the right trick for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [collect the individual character arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html#d119e31399) into a single character array, then use [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to convert it:

```
labels_numeric = str2num([labels{:}]);
```

Or even easier, just use [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html):

```
labels_numeric = str2double(labels);
```

Answer (score 1):

gnovice's answer is the simplest solution to this specific problem, but in general if you want to turn a cell array into a numeric one by applying some transformation to each element you can do so using `cellfun`. For example if you ask MATLAB for `length({'apple' 'orange' 'banana'})` you'll get `3`, but if you want the length of each string in the array you can do:

```
>> cellfun(@length, {'apple' 'orange' 'banana'})

ans =

     5     6     6
```

You can use an anonymous function, or a handle to a function that you have defined, as the argument to `cellfun`, so the transformation can be as complex as you need.

As long as the result from your function is a scalar numeric or logical value, the output from `cellfun` will be a numeric or logical array; otherwise it will be another cell array (and if it varies in size you will need to use the `'UniformOutput', false` argument pair)